# NSImageView subclass not showing image

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsimageview

I'v made a subclass of `NSImageView` because I want to customize some mouseClick events. But, I haven't even started and something went wrong. I'v made `NSImageView` subclass:

(File/New/File... / Cocoa(Objective-C Class) / Class = `NSImageViewME`, Subclass of `NSImageView`).

Just that. I've imported `NSImageViewME.h` and in code where I'm creating Images and adding them to my `NSView`:

```
NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[imageView setImage:image];
[self addSubview:imageView];
```

I'v just replaced `NSImageView` with `NSImageViewME` and image is not being displayed. So, very clear, when I use `NSImageView`, everything works fine but when I use `NSImageViewME` (untouched subclass) image is not being displayed... I've checked, `initWithFrame` is being called, `setImage` is being called but image is not showing... What can be the problem? Cheers.

Comment: 1. you should post the code with your `NSImageViewME` class instead. 2. did you comment out the empty `drawRect:` implementation for your subclass or have it call `super`?

Answer (score 1):

Comment this out:

```
(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
```

Comment: If his subclass has overridden the drawRect: method (and doesn't call [super drawRect:dirtyRect]) then the image drawing method (drawRect:) in the NSImageView class implementation will never be called.